# How to choose between a 32-bit or 64-bit version OS / Como elegir arquitectura

Tags: kernel

Good afternoon,

I already downloaded your OS, but before starting the installation process I'd like to know if at the start of it I will be able to choose if I want to install the 32-bit or 64-bit version of the OS, (this is not appropiately addressed in the download page). If this is not the case, could you please direct me to the download page of the 64-bit version?

I appreciate your help, and I congratulate the team por its elegant and minimalist OS.

---

#### *Original Spanish question*

Buenas tardes

Ya descargue su sistema operativo antes de empezar la instalación me gustaría saber si al comienzo me va a dejar elegir la forma en que quiero instalar si en 32bits o 64bits ya que al momento de descargar no aclaran esto , si no por favor me dan el enlace de descarga de elementary os 64bit.

Les agradezco su ayuda y los felicito por su elegante minimista SO

Answer (score 5):

Starting from elementary OS Loki, the OS is only available for 64-bit CPUs. So if you downloaded the ISO from the [official page](https://elementary.io/), you already have the 64-bit version.

#### *Spanish*

Hola Ruben, desde el lanzamiento de elementary OS Loki, el SO sólo está disponible para arquitecturas de 64 bits. Si descargaste la ISO desde la [página oficial](https://elementary.io/), ya tenés la versión de 64 bits.